# how to get data from multyline json object using Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, http

After an $http get request resource api gives back a multyline json:(example)

```
{"features":["type": "feature", "properties":{ "id": "001", "name": "Example"}]}
```

How can i get an id from that data?

```
$scope.myDate = $http.get('http://example.com/').
  success(function(data, status){
    var test = data.features;
    $scope.information = test['type'];

  }).
  error(function(data, status){
    console.log('not');
  });
```

The way i used isn't correct, so any suggestions?
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: this json seem not valid, features is an array, and contain key-values. Should be an object

Answer (score 1):

Your `JSON` is not valid, you need to change it as follows and then try

```
var data = {
    "features": [{
        "type": "feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "Example"
        }
    }]
};

alert(data.features[0].type);
```

Note: `features` array contains object, so you need to enclose that with `{}`

Comment: If you ever want to test, use http://jslint.com and paste in your json; it will validate it for you.

Comment: thanx, and what if it would be more than one object in feature , should i iterate it first to put the result into an array?

Comment: Yep. `{"features":[{"id":"001"},{"id":"002"}]}`